# how to create a file in a specific folder on desktop by default

Tags: java

I am trying to create a file with data inputted by user. But, I want that to be saved on a new folder on desktop every time user runs it. How can I do that?

```
package my.io;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BufferReader {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.print("Please enter your text!!: ");
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = ip.nextLine();
        FileWriter fWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
          fWriter = new FileWriter("text.txt");
          writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter); 
          writer.write(text);
          writer.newLine();
          writer.close();
          System.err.println("Iput of " + text.length() + " characters was saved on Desktop.");
          System.out.println("Text you have entered is:" + (ip.nextLine()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know where the desktop is, you can use something like...

```
File desktop = new File(System.get("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop");
```

Now, obviously, this is for Windows, for MacOS, you can follow something similar, but you'd need to verify the location from within the `user.home` context...

Now you have the desktop path, you could simply create a folder using something like...

```
File outputFolder = null;
do {
    outputFolder = new File(desktop, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss").format(new Date()));
} while (outputFolder.exists());
if (!outputFolder.mkdirs()) {
    System.err.println("Failed to create output folder " + outputFolder);
}
```

Now, this is just creating folders with a timestamp with a second accuracy.  It might be nice to give the directory a more meaningful name, but that comes down to needs...

The following example is a little more complicated, this basically lists all the directories in the `desktop`, which start with the predetermined `predix`.

It then loops throughs and determines the max number suffix and create a new directory with the next number in the sequence, this means that if you delete a directory, it won't try and overwrite an existing directory...

```
String prefix = "Test";

File[] folders = desktop.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isDirectory()
                        && pathname.getName().startsWith(prefix);
    }
});

System.out.println(folders.length);

int max = 0;
for (File folder : folders) {
    String name = folder.getName();
    name = name.substring(prefix.length()).trim();
    System.out.println(name);

    max = Math.max(max, Integer.parseInt(name));
}
max++;

String suffix = String.format("%04d", max);

File output = new File(desktop, prefix + " " + suffix);
System.out.println(output);
if (!output.exists() && !output.mkdirs()) {
    System.out.println(output + " not created");
}
```